# How can I accomplish this type of URL in ASP.Net MVC2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url

I have a table called Categories. I want the user to click from a list of Categories and then load a listing of all Auctions in that category.

Simple enough, right?

I could create an action for every category, something like:

```
public ActionResult Cellphones()
public ActionResult Electronics
public ActionResult Clothes
public ActionResult Cars
public ActionResult RealEstate
```

This would generate URLs like: /Auctions/Clothes, and /Auctions/RealEstate. Exactly what I'm looking for.

The problem is this requires manual tinkering. When I add a category, I'll have to manually create a new action and then a new view for it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create one ActionResult:

```
public class AuctionController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult AuctionCategoryDetails(string categoryName)
    {
        var model = repository.GetAuctionsForCategory(categoryName);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then create one route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AuctionCategoryDetails",
    "Auctions/{categoryName}",
    new { controller = "Auction", action = "AuctionCategoryDetails" });
```

So when your displaying a list of categories (not individual details);

```
<% foreach (var category in Model.Categories) { %>
   <%: Html.RouteLink("Category Details", "AuctionCategoryDetails", new { categoryName = category.CategoryName });
<% } %>
```

That will produce a list of links like this:

```
<a href="/Auctions/Clothes">Category Details</a>
<a href="/Auctions/RealEstate">Category Details</a>
```

Is that what your after?

Comment: Weird - code sample's on Stack have been messed up the last couple of days.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I'll mold this into what I'm looking for. Thanks a bunch for the help! :)

Comment: @RPM1984: The issues I've seen lately are all with the live preview. They come out fine in the actual posts.

Comment: @BoltClock - but look at my answer. The first two code samples are messed up (no syntax highlighting), and yet the last two are fine. Weird.

Comment: @RPM1984: Wow, in that case I dunno. Tried twice to mess with whitespace, doesn't seem to help. Ask on meta, perhaps?

Comment: @BoltClock - look! It's magically fixed itself 7 hours later. We got ourselves a black magic woman!

Comment: @RPM1984: Still stuck on this. I've implemented everything in your answer, but I'm stuck on actually using the controller. Since I'm using the _layout.cshtml file to render the menu everywhere, it seems I can't use a controller. Suggestions? I'm so frustrated right now.

Comment: @Serg - what do you mean "can't use a controller"? - where does this question mention a menu, are you sure your not referring to one of your other questions? You should probably open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called URL routing. You map your categories to a single `AuctionController` action, which serves and displays category data dynamically based on what's in the URL.

There's a tutorial on [the ASP.NET MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) that covers the ground basics.

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing that link. I'm afraid I don't really comprehend how to use routing to accomplish my goal. Can I trouble you for some more guidance? Thank you.